# How can I fix the 'Error in PyMuPDF' when installing paddleocr with pip?

Tags: pip, pymupdf, paddleocr

When doing `pip install paddleocr`, I am facing an error in building wheel for PyMuPDF.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: PyMuPDF
Building wheel for PyMuPDF (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [70 lines of output]



Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\3551\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ip72hta1\pymupdf_f7a2c6bc313a492fa6c66ad0817a4616\setup.py", line 487, in <module>
          mupdf_local = get_mupdf()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\3551\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ip72hta1\pymupdf_f7a2c6bc313a492fa6c66ad0817a4616\setup.py", line 450, in get_mupdf
          return tar_extract( mupdf_tgz, exists='return')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\3551\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ip72hta1\pymupdf_f7a2c6bc313a492fa6c66ad0817a4616\setup.py", line 183, in tar_extract
          t.extractall()
        File "C:\Users\3551\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2059, in extractall
          self.extract(tarinfo, path, set_attrs=not tarinfo.isdir(),
        File "C:\Users\3551\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2100, in extract
          self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name),
        File "C:\Users\3551\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2173, in _extract_member
          self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
        File "C:\Users\3551\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2214, in makefile
          with bltn_open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\mupdf-1.20.3-source\\thirdparty\\harfbuzz\\test\\shaping\\texts\\in-house\\shaper-indic\\script-devanagari\\utrrs\\codepoint\\IndicFontFeatureCodepoint-AdditionalConsonants.txt'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyMuPDF
  Running setup.py clean for PyMuPDF
Failed to build PyMuPDF
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyMuPDF, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried doing `pip install wheel` and installing the PyMuPDF using pip by `pip install PyMuPDF` then install paddleocr by `pip install paddleocr` but the same problem is there error building wheel file for PyMuPDF.

I am using a `intel i3, 64` bit processor
and python version is `3.11.3`

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy/paste the complete error message into your question, using the [edit] feature. Then put it in code formatting by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button. this way, they are much more readable and accessible. You will only increase the number of people that actually read your question through

Comment: Also include information about your OS and python setup

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I updated my question as per it

Comment: Are you fixed on using python 3.11 or would you be willing to switch to a lower version?

Comment: `paddleocr` has the requirement `PyMuPDF<1.21.0` and `PyMuPDF==1.20.2` (the latest version that fits the `paddleocr` requirement) only has whl files up to python 3.10

Comment: If it is absolutely necessary I can switch to lower version of python, else I would like to stick to 3.11
so to make it compatible I need to switch back to python 3.10.
Thank you very much

Comment: can you check which version your system is trying to install, there should be a line in your output that says something about `pymupdfXXX.tar.gz` where XXX is the version number?

Comment: Try to download https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/mupdf-1.22.0-source.tar.gz extract it and then set the environment variable `PYMUPDF_SETUP_MUPDF_BUILD` to the path of the extracted `mupdf-1.22.0` location. Then try the installation again

Comment: it is trying to install `pymupdf 1.20.2 .tar.gz`

Comment: Should download https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/mupdf-1.20.3-source.tar.gz and setup the environment variable as described above

Comment: Or try to download and install the whl file from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PESjDkovpvnrWFTKji4-qgT3rcVz-o-F?usp=sharing and then do `pip install <that whl file>`. it should install `pymupdf`, then you can `pip install paddleocr`

Comment: Downloading the wheel file and install worked for me thank you very much!!

Comment: @FlyingTeller yours is the answer I needed. Please write it as an answer, not just a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`paddleocr` has the requirement `PyMuPDF<1.21.0` and `PyMuPDF==1.20.2` (the latest version that fits the paddleocr requirement) only has whl files up to python 3.10. Therefor, `pip` falls back to trying to install from source.

The exact error message is from the install script of `PyMuPDF` trying to download one of its dependencies, which fails during extraction of the `.tar.gz` file. You have different options  now:

1. Manually download https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/mupdf-1.20.3-source.tar.gz then extract the archive to a path of your choosing. Set the environment variable `PYMUPDF_SETUP_MUPDF_BUILD` to the path of the extracted `mupdf-1.20.3` folder and try to run `pip install PyMuPDF==1.20.2`. Note that you will also need a working compiler for this approach
2. Download this unofficial whl file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PESjDkovpvnrWFTKji4-qgT3rcVz-o-F?usp=sharing and install it with `pip install <path to the whl file>`

Answer (score 12):

Try this one
pip install "paddleocr>=2.0.1" --upgrade PyMuPDF==1.21.1
it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

For the developers who are facing this issue on macOS, you need to install `pip install PyMuPDF==1.20.0` as PaddleOCR requires `PyMuPDF<1.21.0`.

If you are still facing the `ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyMuPDF` issue then try `brew install swig` first and then try `pip install PyMuPDF==1.20.0` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

An update:
Just you need to install `siwg`, you can follow these steps on arch-based distrubtions:

- Install swig: `pamac install swig`
- Install PuMyPDF: `pip install PyMuPDF`
- Then Install PaddleOCR: `pip install paddlepaddle paddleocr`